# Best polygonal approximation to a polynomial $\pm$ c

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, polynomials, discrete-geometry, plane-geometry

Let a planar region $R$ be defined
by the vertical range bounded by
a polynomial $f(x) \pm c$ with $c>0$ a constant,
and with $x$ varying between the smallest and largest
roots of $f(x)$.
For example, 
\begin{eqnarray}
f(x)&=& (x - 1)^2 (x - 2) (x - 3) (x - 4)\\
f(x) &\pm& \tfrac{1}{2} 
\end{eqnarray}
within $x \in [1,4]$.

Now I would like to connect the smallest and largest
roots of $f(x)$ with a polygonal line of fewest links
that remains in $R$.
In the example, between $(1,0)$ to $(4,0)$:

---

[image: LinnkParallel]

---

Here, $4$ (red) links within (the blue) $R$ suffice, and $3$ are insufficient.

Let $L(f,c)$ be the fewest links to connect 
the extreme roots within the region $R$ bounded by $f \pm c$.

As $c \to 0$, $L(f,c) \to \infty$, except for very special $f$.
And as $c \to \infty$,  $L(f,c) \to 1$.
In the example above, when 
$c \gt 2.63628$, $L(f,c)=1$, because then
the min of $f(x)$ at $x\approx 3.65374$ 
is raised by $+c$ to lie
above the $x$-axis so that
$(1,0)$ can see $(4,0)$ directly horizontally.

So, finally!, my question is:

> ***Q***.
>   Given a fixed polynomial of maximum degree $d$ 
>   ($d{=}5$ in the above example),
>   how does $L(f,c)$ vary as a function of $c$?

I am ultimately interested in calculating $L(f,c)$ for specific $f$ and $c$,
but that does not seem straightforward, so I first seek some
insight into the overall behavior.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't really about polynomials, just about how big $|f''|$ gets.
For small $c$, a segment of length $\delta$ must have $|f''| \, \delta^2 \ll c$, 
so for fixed nonlinear $f$ it will take about $c^{-1/2}$ segments.

Comment: ("length $\delta$" in the $x$-direction, naturally.)

Comment: I see, using a quadratic approximation. Clever & clean---Thanks!